How to return only certain objects and key-value pairs from array in Snowflake
Consider the following table in Snowflake:



Column_Name
Type




order_id
int


cust_id
varchar


details
variant



Sample Data:
with sample_data as (
 select 1 as order_id, 'aaa' as cust_id, 
    '{
      "channel": "phone",
      "result": "approved", 
      "reason": null,
      "pairs": [
        {
          "key": "size",
          "value": "large"
        },
        {
          "key": "color",
          "value": "red"
        },
        {
          "key": "fit",
          "value": "slim"
        },
        {
          "key": "pattern",
          "value": "zebra"
        }
      ]
    }' as details union all
 select 2 as order_id, 'bbb' as cust_id, 
    '{
      "channel": "store",
      "result": "denied", 
      "reason": "stock",
      "pairs": [
        {
          "key": "size",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "key": "pattern",
          "value": "tiger"
        }
      ]
    }' as details
)
select *
from sample_data

Each array may contain dozens or hundreds of objects and key-value pairs, but I only want certain ones. So from the sample data, I would like to extract only the channel object, result object and certain pairs (where key is size or color).
Desired Output for ORDER_ID 1:
{
  "channel": "phone",
  "result": "approved", 
  "pairs": [
    {
      "key": "size",
      "value": "large"
    },
    {
      "key": "color",
      "value": "red"
    }
  ]
}

Desired Output for ORDER_ID 2:
{
  "channel": "store",
  "result": "denied", 
  "pairs": [
    {
      "key": "size",
      "value": null
    }
  ]
}

The full desired output would look like:



order_id
cust_id
details




1
aaa
the desired array above for order 1


2
bbb
the desired array above for order 2



I can use lateral_flatten() within a CTE to allow me to then filter the "pairs" that I want, but I'm not sure how to: (1) put the desired pairs back together as an array, or; (2) add "channel" and "result" objects back to my modified array. I'm not using array_construct in the right manner as it's returning a row for every object. Was hoping it could be used like a windows fuction (partition by) but it doesn't work that way.

FILTER + lambda : SELECT t.order_id, t.cust_id, OBJECT_INSERT(OBJECT_DELETE(t.details, 'pairs', 'reason'), 'pairs', FILTER(t.details:pairs, a->a:key::TEXT IN ('size', 'color') )) AS details FROM sample_data t;

@LukaszSzozda Thank you for these two options. I don't believe I can use object_delete because there are dozens or hundreds of objects and I won't know the names of them. I only know the names of one's to keep, and some of those may require some unique wildcarding. However, I think this gets me down the right path. I'll work on the pairs first and worry about the other objects later.

Then OBJECT_PICK + FILTER is the way to go: SELECT t.order_id, t.cust_id,  OBJECT_INSERT(OBJECT_PICK(t.details, ['channel', 'result']), 'pairs', FILTER(t.details:pairs, a->a:key::TEXT IN ('size', 'color') )) AS details FROM sample_data t;

@LukaszSzozda Wow, A+ work thank you. Much better than some crazy other solution I was working on. If you add as an answer then I'll accept it.

Using a higher order function FILTER and object functions(pick/insert) to build required structure:
SELECT t.order_id,
       t.cust_id,
       OBJECT_INSERT(OBJECT_PICK(t.details, ['channel', 'result']), 'pairs', 
                    FILTER(t.details:pairs, a->a:key::TEXT IN ('size', 'color'))
       ) AS details 
FROM sample_data t;

Output:

